# AS3 / If button clicked reset it to false

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I come to the text field type the button appear
and if I get the text from the text that the button is disappeared. Now I want that when I click on the button to move the button is disappeared again and go to the next page.(movieClip).

I do everything in a frame and use addChild and removeChild to maneuver between the different pages. The butting stay the same all the time. (only make it visible/invisible)

so I do the same again. Is this possible and how can I do it best?

For now it remains visible on the second page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want dig into creating custom classes you could use this code
First place define some functions

```
import fl.controls.Button;
var pairs={}; 
var funcs={};
function ButtonConstructor(btnName:String,initX:Number,initY:Number,
                           connectedTF:TextField,clickFunction:Function){
    this[btnName] = new Button();
    this[btnName].x=initX;
    this[btnName].name=btnName;
    this[btnName].y=initY;
    this[btnName].visible =false;
    this[btnName].addEventListener('click',typicalClick);
    addChild(this[btnName]);
    pairs[connectedTF.name]=this[btnName];
    funcs[btnName]=clickFunction;
    connectedTF.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,tfChange);
}
function tfChange(e:Event){
    pairs[e.target.name].enabled = true;
    pairs[e.target.name].visible = true;
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.CHANGE,tfChange);
}
function typicalClick(e:MouseEvent){
    e.target.enabled = false;
    e.target.visible = false;
    funcs[e.target.name]();
}
```

Then you use them

```
function customFunction(){
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
ButtonConstructor('newBtn',100,100,firstTF,customFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

The button object is not scoped to be accessible within the `handler` function. You have to either see if it can be accessed via the event object that is passed to the `handler` function or create a custom event class that will contain the button object that can then be accessed in the `handler` function when you dispatch the change event for the textfield.